# threejs - Calibrate Stereo effect: is distorted with larger phones

Tags: javascript, three.js, stereo-3d, virtual-reality

**How can I calibrate the camera in threeJS so that both images have different points of focus?** You can see in this image that the left stereo image is looking farther right than the right stereo image.

[image]

I wish to know how to change where each image is focused.

**The full-story:**
I use stereo effect when using VR glasses with phones. When looking at VR using a small phone like an iPhone 6, the image is crystal clear but on the iPhone 6 Plus, everything is blurry.

My theory is that the center of each lens must align with the center of each stereo image and this is how we can obtain focus. (see the second image)

Here is how i initiate the stereo effect.

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
effect = new THREE.StereoEffect(renderer);
function render() {
  effect.render(scene, camera);
}
function resize() {
  var width = container.offsetWidth;
  var height = container.offsetHeight;

  camera.aspect = width / height;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(width, height);
  effect.setSize(width, height);
}
function update(dt) {
  resize();
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}
```

[image]